# How to enable the ApplicationIdleDetectionMode in windows phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-8

I was able to set the ApplicationIdleDetectionMode to disabled. And it runs even when the screen is locked.

Now I want to enable it back. I have given a toggle switch to the user for this.
But when i enable it , it throws an exception.I could handle the exception in catch block .When I restart the app it is enabled again.

Do we need to tell the end user to restart the app upon turning this to off(i.e. enabling the applicationidledetectionmode).Any workaround for this ?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot disable application idle detection once you have enabled it, as shown [in the exception section of the MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.shell.phoneapplicationservice.applicationidledetectionmode%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). You will need to inform users that they will need to restart the app.